# Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object[Normal]

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm facing following error from my AJAX called php script. Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object. Actually I have written a Stored procedure to create dynamic temporary table. Please find below the Stored procedure and php script for call stored procedure.

```
`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `StoreValue`(IN `Clname` VARCHAR(55), IN `ip_a` VARCHAR(55), IN `port_n` INT, IN `table_1` VARCHAR(55), IN `variable1` VARCHAR(55), IN `moddate1` TIMESTAMP, IN `moddate2` TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(55);
SET @table_name := table_1;

set @sql_text:=concat('create temporary table ',@table_name,'(status varchar(100),moddate datetime,INDEX mod_index (moddate)) '," SELECT `status`,`moddate` FROM `globstats_graph` WHERE Cname=? and ip=? and port=? and Variable=? and status REGEXP '^[0-9]+$|^ON$' and moddate between ? and ?");  

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
set @a=Clname;
set @b=ip_a;
set @c=port_n;
set @d=variable1;
set @e=moddate1;
set @f=moddate2;
 EXECUTE stmt USING @a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f;
END`
```

php code:
for connection

```
try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username, $password);
} 
catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

for call stored procedure

```
try {
            // execute the stored procedure
            $sql = "CALL StoreValue('$client','$ip','$port','$table_name','$var','$new_start','$new_end')";
            $q = $conn->query($sql);
            $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $total_search=$q->rowCount();
        } catch (PDOException $pe) {

            echo die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
        }
```

Please help me out from this problem...

Comment: Did $conn->query($sql) returned a value? If not check the error code/error message, it might give you useful information.

Comment: @cristik var_dump($conn->query($sql)) shows bool(false).what should i do?Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $q variable is not an object, this causes the fatal error. Most likely the $conn->query() method call returned the problematic value, and you will need to dig a little bit to find out why the `query()` method failed.

One of the best places to start searching is the PDO documentation to see what support it has for error reporting. Particularly, I think you'll find this user comment very interesting, considering the fact that you wrapped the query code into a try/catch block: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#74943.

> The handling of errors by this function is controlled by the attribute PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE.
>
> Use the following to make it throw an exception:
> <?php
> $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
> ?>

Comment: Hi @cristik thanks for ur reply. I found the problem statement. **Error occurred:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'mongraph'@'%' to database 'mymonitor'** pdo object is not getting created. it throws mentioned error. please help me to connect database through pdo object following are the parameters, username=****, passwor=**** and hostname=localhost. i suspect hostname value instead of localhost may i use ip address?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Did you granted access for user "mongraph" to the "mymonitor" database? If you are not sure if you did, you you don't know how to check, you can try connection with the "root" user and password either "root", empty, or the one that you defined when you installed mysql. This will solve the problem for your development machine, however this solution is appropriate to use only on local machines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @cristik. Actually that was grant permission issue. now it is working fine.... thanks.